# multiple or conditions in if else statements best way oracle pl sql

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql

I have below scenario where i have to check multiple or conditions to check if local varibale should not be equal to A, B, C, D and so on. Obviously real values are different than I refered here. I want to know which one is the best from below or any other possible way:

```
IF(condition1 AND (myLocalVAr NOT IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F') ) ) THEN
----
--
END IF;
```

or

```
IF(condition1 AND (myLocalVAr <> 'A' AND myLocalVAr <> 'B' AND myLocalVAr <> 'C'--'D'--'E'--'F' --so on) ) ) THEN
----
--
END IF;
```

Comment: `val not in (1, 2, 3)` means `val <> 1 AND val <>2 AND val <>3`, not "OR" as you seem to think. Other than that, the "NOT IN" version is much easier to read, write, and maintain, and both forms are processed the same way by the database engine, so you should prefer the "NOT IN" version.

Comment: oh Yah I forgot I wrote OR. You are correct I should have written AND instead of OR.

Comment: For all we know, the PL/SQL compiler already re-writes the first version into the second one anyway. I'm sure it does whatever is most efficient, and we should probably be focussing on clear, correct, maintainable code. btw there are no brackets around `if` conditions.

Answer (score 2):

In real world we always looking to think and code in simple and automated ways and methods, if we can't achieve our goal, then we have to looking to more complex solutions.

now let's see your code,
the first way is more easy straightforward to achieve your goal, if the source of A, B, C, D,...etc is from table we can directly write it like:

```
myLocalVAr not in (select column_name from table_name)
```

this is working fine, and any new value will be easy to handle by this approach, however "not in" clause has disadvantages:

1. you have to be sure that the return values in subquery do not have any single null value, if it does, then the whole logic will be null, in this case we can handle it by using nvl function or eliminate null records by using where clause.
2. performance: the "not in" clause does not give us a good performance when we have a long list of values which we compre myLocalVAr with it. so we are using here "not exists" instead.

the second approach you are mentioned is not practical, it is hard working, error born, and hard to manage with new values in the future, you have to add new values by yourself and modify this code every time you need to compare with new value, so we do not follow solutions like this one.

Comment: not exists can work for sql queries but not for pl-sql syntax IF(condition1 AND (myLocalVAr NOT exists ('A','B','C','D','E','F') ) ) THEN...wont work